# Parsing strings with single quotation marks in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, char, escaping

If I have a string like: 'I can't parse this' with a single quotation mark in between, how can I remove that without getting a syntax error, and return ICANTPARSETHIS? I know that it would work if it was "I can't parse this" instead, but I am looking at a problem where the potential input might not have double quotation marks surrounding it.

Comment: The quotation mark is only a syntax error in string literals, and can be handled by proper quoting or using a triple-quoted string.

Comment: But it sounds as if you are trying to handle program input instead, in which case it is *not a problem*. What *exactly* are you trying to do here?

Comment: If you are using `input()` in Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead and avoid having your input being treated as Python expressions altogether.

Comment: I am not asking the user for any input. My program will be tested by an auto marker, which will be calling my functions, and I think it will only be using single quotation marks around any given string. @MartijnPieters

Comment: please post sample input and expected output as well as any code you have written to attempt this.  as It stands this will end up getting closed as it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: That is a bit of a leap; and that would specifically be a problem for the auto-marker, not *your code*.

Comment: The auto-marker would pass in a string *value*. How the auto-marker generated that string is not your problem; once you have a string value you can, by definition, not have a syntax error.

Comment: Am I right in interpreting the question that you are parsing text and all the quotes (beginning and end and apostrophe in "can't" are all part of the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misunderstood something here. There is no problem here at all.

Syntax errors only apply to source code. String values are *not* source code.

If your source code uses string *literals*, Python parses those and produces a string *value*. The string literal can have a syntax error in it, but if without errors, it will produce a string value that is just that, a value.

In the Python interpreter such string values are represented using the same format as a string literal, for ease of debugging and copying back into the interpreter. Rest assured that the Python interpreter knows how to escape quotes in such values correctly:

```
>>> """Text with a single quote: '"""
"Text with a single quote: '"""
>>> """We can use a double quote too: ". See?"""
'We can use a double quote too: ". See?'
>>> """Even mixing " and ' is not a problem."""
'Even mixing " and \' is not a problem.'
```

I used triple-quoted literal syntax there, but Python echos alternatives that use the minimum quoting style required, and escapes quote symbols as needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
print "Parse 'this string' to something".split()
print re.findall(some_pattern,"this is a string with `internal quotation` marks")
print 'quotes' == "quotes" == """quotes""" == '''quotes''' == u'quotes' == u"quotes"
```

Im not sure what your question is ... but these two examples demonstrate that you can parse strings with internal quote marks

also demonstrates that quotes are all the same basically

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding is that you want to remove the apostrophe on the "can't"?

```
'I can't parse this'.replace("'", "")
>>> 'I cant parse this'
```

or if you have it in a variable:

```
s = 'I can\'t parse this'
s.replace("'", "")
>>> 'I cant parse this'
```

Edit: As pointed out the second example was a syntax error without the escape character on the apostrophe.

Comment: I had forgot the escape character, but that essentially sets the str to a double quoted str with the single quote still in there.

Comment: **Exactly**, which illustrates that the OP didn't understand what is going on here. Do you?

Comment: I do understand, I miss understood the OP that he/she wasn't using literals, rather potential input. Also I don't usually test questions like this so mistyping in a input box was just a doozy. My bad.